# Headless RaspberryPi SSH connection through Ethernet USBC adapter

Tags: ssh, ethernet, port-forwarding

I have a headless Raspberry Pi with SSH enabled. I can program with no issues using VSCode remotely using a Windows Laptop.

But, I'm now using a one of those "fancy" new laptops with Linux and without Ethernet ports and Id like to connect to my Raspberry-Pi.

So the setup is:

- Raspberry Pi *--ethernetcable-->* USBC Ethernet Adapter *--USBC Cable-->* Linux PC.

SSH is enabled on the Pi and I am trying to connect to it with VSCode

I've read that `ip -4 addr show scope global` might help but my device doesn't show the actual IP.

Any ideas on how to actually implement it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can connect the Pi to the router over ethernet. Then your laptop would connect to the router over WiFi. Then two will be able to talk through the router

Comment: That might work, but I dont really have physical access to the router, or might even have the credentials for it in order to work :/

Comment: That port forwarding question is irrelevant. You just need to set different static IPs on both sides and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Daniel T !! My ethernet adaptor was not using IPv4, it was defaulting to IPv6.

After defaulting to IPv4, setting static IP adresses and doing ssh pi@[IP of the PI] instead of ssh pi@raspberrypi I can connect to this device through VS Code.

Thank you for the support!